# error: Mandatory attribute 'id' for tag 'action' is missing

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing a problem of mentioned title.

**What I did before:**
I used a command **`ctrl+alt+shift+i`** to remove the unused resources. But after removing the unused resources and ids, I can't even build the project properly.

**What I've tried:**
I did -

- Invalidate cache and restart android studio
- Clean project and rebuild

So, What can I do to get rid of this problem. Please let me know.

Comment: Kindly update question with build logs, it might point to the line where you are getting error.

Comment: @ShadowDroid I shared what I am getting. There is nothing more I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry for delay reply, but from the error line you posted I could say that somewhere in your code, you have used view.getTag(R.id.someId,somevalue). In cleanup you removed unnecessary views so probably someId doesnot exist anymore or it has been change to view.getTag(somevalue). kindly check build logs in Android Studio it should show exact class file where you are getting error.

Answer (score 2):

if you using navigation architecture component, maybe your navigation graph, for an unknown reason somehow your destination id get removed. you can add it manually

```
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
    android:name="com.daya.knownliga.view.ui.search.SearchFragment"
    android:label="fragment_search"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search">
    <action
        app:destination="@id/detailMatchFragment" />
</fragment>
```

notice there is no id in action tag, you can add it like this :

```
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
    android:name="com.daya.knownliga.view.ui.search.SearchFragment"
    android:label="fragment_search"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_searchFragment_to_detailMatchFragment"
        app:destination="@id/detailMatchFragment" />
</fragment>
```

usually the navigation id has a format like this

```
action_currentFragment_to_whereverFragment
```

Comment: Sorry, but I had checked already about that. That was totally fine. Thanks for your suggestion anyways. :)

Answer (score 2):

The id got removed for me when I did "Remove Unused Resources" and checked the box to remove unused ids. They need to fix that.

Comment: In my case the same thing just happened when I did a "Remove Unused Resources", and all the IDs from within my nav_host.xml file were removed. Thanks for this pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your navigation XML file -> Local history -> Show history.

Then just return the code before deletion.

Hope this helps

Comment: If you ever used "Remove Unused Resources" and having the missing id issue, the above answer is the best, just revert the deletion.